# Finding $\det (AC + C)$ given the matrix $A$ and $\det(C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given a matrix:
$$ A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  5&3\\
  -4&2
\end{array}
\right] $$
and a matrix $C$ with the assumption that $\det(C)=1/5$.

The question is asking me to calculate the determinant of $AC + C$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: $\det (AC+C)=\det(A+I)\det C $.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{split}\det(AC+C)&=\det(AC+IC)\\&=\det\left((A+I)C\right)\\
&=\det(A+I)\det C \text { determinants are multiplicative}\\
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}6&3\\-4&3\end{pmatrix}\det C\\
&=(18--12)\det C \text{ use rule for determinant of a 2x2 matrix}\\
&=30\det C\end{split}$$